# Shopify Storefront GraphQL 403 Forbidden

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I have a custom app I'm building and it has all of the access the app could need. I'm passing in the application storefront access token but am getting a 403 error of 'Forbidden'.

Here is my query:

```
const shopifyUserQuery = `mutation  {
    customerCreate(
      input: {
        firstName: ${values.firstName},
        lastName: ${values.lastName},
        email: ${values.email},
        password: ${values.password}  
      }
    ) {
      customer {
        id,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
      }
      customerUserErrors {
        field,
        message,
      }
      customer {
        id
      }
    }
  }`
```

And then here is the fetch call:

```
const shopifyUser = await fetch(process.env.SHOPIFY_SF_API_URL, {
    'body': shopifyUserQuery,
    'method': 'post',
    'headers': {
      'X-Shopify-Access-Token': process.env.SHOPIFY_SF_API_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
    },
  }).then((sres) => console.log(sres))
```

Any help is appreciated as I'm currently at a loss.

Comment: Shopify defines a 403 as: The shop is forbidden. Returned if the store has been marked as fraudulent.

Comment: @DavidLazar but this makes absolutely no sense. What does that even mean?

Comment: I don't know. Ask Shopify. They made the API. Apparently, you are calling a store they consider to be out of business or something.

Comment: For using storefront access token - headers should have 
X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token 

[check this](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront#authentication)

Answer (score 0):

A little late to answer; but it should be `X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token` not `X-Shopify-Access-Token`, the `X-Shopify-Access-Token` is for when you're trying to access the Admin API, and it accepts merchant session accessToken as its value.

The content type also should be `application/json`.

But I suggest you to use the official shopify package for node(`@shopify/shopify-api`) in order to use API/GraphQL.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/shopify-api